# My picture isn't appearing, DOM loading issues?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, onload, appendchild

I'm not really sure what is wrong, I run the code in browser and it seems like the image flickers briefly before completely disappearing. I tried to use window.onload but that either doesn't work or shows the picture before I click the button.

```js
window.onload = function final() {
  var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = "q1"]:checked').value;
  var color = document.querySelector('input[name = "q2"]:checked').value;

  if (gender == "girl" && color == "blue") {
    alert("girl blue");
    finalpic();
  } else if (gender == "girl" && color == "red") {
    alert("girl red");
  } else if (gender == "guy" && color == "blue") {
    alert("guy blue");
  } else if (gender == "guy" && color == "red") {
    alert("guy red");
  }
}

function finalpic() {
  var img1 = document.createElement("img");
  img1.src = "https://i.imgur.com/VyEdgNu.jpg";
  var sauce = document.getElementById("results");
  sauce.appendChild(img1);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> Survey</legend>

    <p>Gender</p>
    <input type="radio" id="op1" name="q1" value="girl"> Girl<br>
    <input type="radio" id="op2" name="q1" value="guy"> Guy<br>

    <p>Fav Color</p>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="blue">Blue <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="red">Red<br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="final()">

    <div id="results">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I don't think stackoverflow has the No Wrap option and defaults to Onload so here is also the jsfiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/thbu703m/

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting and this causes a page reload. In order to stop refreshing the page and get your image in place, you should prevent the form submission.

Easiest option to do it is add an inline event handler:

```
 <form onsubmit="return false">
```

instead of your

```
 <form>
```